# Initwithnibname:bundle: can't load xib with 2 view controllers from a resource bundle

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, bundle, nsviewcontroller

The latter part of the question may not matter; but I am having an issue loading 2 viewcontrollers from a xib that I have put into a resource bundle.

These are the steps I've taken:

1)Create a new target, of type bundle.  In the copy resource bundles, I added the xib I wanted for this bundle.

2)Added this bundle as a target dependency in my main app target, so that it'll build the bundle with the xib

3)In my Products group, the bundle appears, I dragged this reference into Copy Bundle Resources in the build phase of my main app target.

4)I run and build, and try to load the nib in my windowcontroller with

```
self.accountController = [myAccountController initWithAccount:account];
//At this point, accountController is initialized correctly, 
//but neither of the view controllers are initialized;
//so this view is nil.  see below for more info
NSView* myView = self.accountController.myViewController1.view;
```

// This is the accountController implementation:

```
//This method is custom, because I need some arguments in my init
-(instancetype) initWithAccount:(myAccount*)account
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:myNibName bundle:[self resourceBundle]
   if(self)
   {
      self.account = account;
   }
   return self;
}

+(NSBundle*) resourceBundle
{
   NSURL* bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:myBundleName withExtension:@"bundle"];
   NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:bundleURL];

   NSError* error = nil;
   [bundle loadAndReturnError:&error];
   NSLog(@"%@", error);

   return bundle;
}
```

The bundle returned is correct, it points to the correct location, and all the names are correct.  But after the `initWithNibName:bundle:` call, self does not have the 2 view controllers I have defined in the nib.

I want to say it has something to do with the fact that initwithnibname doesn't actually load the nib that contains the view controllers?  But my understanding is shakey and the apple nib documentation isn't really reaching me.  I also could be creating my VC's in my xib wrong...

Could anybody help spell this out for me? I've basically spent the whole day banging my head on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp I'm sure there's a better solution, but mine ended up just accessing the `view` property of the base view controller, and it would then go and load the view controllers declared in the xib